# Queue Priority in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

In my build configuration I have multiple project queues:

```
Queue1, Queue2, ... Queue(N)
```

I want to configure the build where I can set the priority of when each queue builds:

```
Queue1 = Priority of 2, Queue2 = Priority of 1 ...
```

which produces the queues being built in the following order:

```
Queue2, Queue1 ...
```

How can I accomplish this in CruiseControl.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with CruiseControl.NET - each queue is seperate, so they all run independently. The only exception to this is using the lockqueues property - but this does not allow setting the priority.

Comment: +1 I came to the same conclusion myself.  Welcome to StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, priorities are assigned inside a queue i.e., projects that belong to the same queue are ranked by their priority. Consider the following configuration:

```
<project name="Project 1" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
<project name="Project 2" queue="Q1" queuePriority="2">
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
<project name="Project 3" queue="Q2" queuePriority="1">
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

Project 1 is executed prior to Project 2, but Project 1 and Project 3 are executed in arbitrary order (or even parallel), since they belong to different queues.

Comment: I understand that, what I want to do is prioritize the queues.